# create own library in windows phone development

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is It possible to create library in windows phone development just like jar file .If it is possible so please tell me how i create library or provide me some link so i will complete my task.

Thanks & Regards 
Zakir Hussain

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Windows Phone Class library which would enable you to use the library withing any windows phone UI project that targets the same version.

File > New Project > Other Languages > Silverlight for windows Phone > Windows phone class library

Alternatively (and my preferred option), you can create a Portable Class library, to target Windows phone 7.5/8 and windows 8 store apps.

file > New Project > Visual c# > Windows > Portable Class Library

[See some resources on PCL here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714086%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[image]